# Accessing Object getter property in reducer function

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I would like to reduce down into a string, depending on whether or not the "duration" property of each object is greater than the global time constant.

```
    const time = 90;

const segments = (time) => [
  {
      duration: 120,
      get run() {
          return (this.duration - time) + "First string"
      }
  },
  {
      duration: 140,
      get run() {
        return (this.duration - time) + " Second string"
      }
  }
];

const stringBuilder = (currentVal, accumulator) => {
  console.log(currentVal.run); // Returns undefined
  return accumulator += (currentVal.duration > time) ? currentVal.run : "";
}

const speech = segments(time).reduce(stringBuilder, ""); // Returns "[object Object]"
```

The problem is that I can't seem to access the getter run() property of my object in the reducer function, it just returns undefined!

Comment: You got the parameters in the wrong order. The accumulator is passed as first argument, the current value is the second argument.

Comment: Btw, this doesn't look like a job for `reduce` to me. `segments().filter(s => s.duration > time).map(s => s.run).join(' ')`